# add/remove Div Class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let me start by saying that I am new to all of this but trying to learn. With that said, I have been racking my brain to figure out how to get a div class to be added/removed with a button id. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated as I have about 200 of these text boxes to make. Attached is the sample html (for use in wordpress with thesis theme) and the css I am using. I have also included a link to jsfiddle so that you can see what I am trying to accomplish (but have failed at).

http://jsfiddle.net/EXPH77/rz683/

CSS:

```
#the_box {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #oooooo;
  background-color: #ddddee;
  width: 320px;

}

.box_header {
  padding-top: .5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #477ede;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  font-size:1.2em;

}

.box_text {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size:0.84em;

}

.media {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;

}

.box_expand {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size:0.84em;

}

p.headtext {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size:1.2em;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="the_box">
<div class="box_header"> Exercise Title </div> 
<div class="media"> 
<iframe width="300" height="195" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ok97QIq2f4E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
</div> 
<div class="box_text"> 
<p class="headtext">Muscles</p> 
<ul style="list-style: none; "> 
  <li><strong>Primary:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;MM</li> 
  <li><strong>Secondary:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;MM</li>
<button id="addClass">Instructions</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#addClass").click(function () {    
      $('#the_box').addClass('box_expand');
    $("#removeClass").click(function () {
      $('#the_box').removeClass('box_expand');
    });  
</script>
</div> <div class="box_expand"> 
<p class="headtext">Preparation</p> 
<ol> 
  <li>Instructions</li> 
  <li>Go</li> <li>Right</li> 
  <li>Here</li> 
</ol> 
<p class="headtext">Movement</p> 
<ol> 
  <li>Instructions</li> 
  <li>Go</li> 
  <li>Right</li> 
  <li>Here</li> 
</ol> 
<p class="headtext">Comments/Tips</p> 
<ul> 
  <li>Instructions</li> 
  <li>Go</li> 
  <li>Here</li> 
</ul> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean here: "div class to be added/removed with a button id". Do you want to add a class to a div when a button is clicked? Also, are you remembering to call the JavaScript Library?

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: You have missed `})` for your first click handler http://jsfiddle.net/rz683/5/ there is no element with class of `removeClass` in your markup, please post all the necessary markup and note that IDs must be unique, if you have many boxes you should use classes instead.

Comment: Are you saying you want to hide the instructions data by default and when the button is clicked it is toggled shown/hidden?

Comment: also, your jsfiddle is set to mootools, which probably doesn't help it work :)

Comment: Thank for everyone's help. The expected behavior was to add a div class when the button was clicked. I have since changed that to a div id and it is accomplishing most of what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ol afll; call jQuery libary to the DOM and always use [**document.ready()**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) when you need to initualise a function on jQuery.

Second thing, you forgot to close first click function with this: `)};`

**Edit:** If you want to show and hide the selector; *[Here is working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qaAfk/4/)*

**jQuery:** and if you want to this with animation, you can use `fadeOut() fadeIn()` methods.

```
$("#hide").click(function () {
    $('#the_box').fadeOut(300);
    //$('#the_box').hide();
});
$("#show").click(function () {
    $('#the_box').fadeIn(300);
    //$('#the_box').show();
});
```

**html:**

```
<div id="the_box"> The Box </div>
<button id="hide"> Hide </button>
<button id="show"> Show </button>​
```

Comment: thank you for the help. So maybe I need a different function then? I am trying to hide/show div class= "box_expand"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have modified it to fit my CSS. I ended up making the div I wanted to hid an Id instead of a class and it seams to work fine. My only only question would be, is there a way to make it load already with the div id="box_expand" hidden? If not I understand. An I appreciate the help you have given me.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EXPH77/eWHSJ/2/)

Comment: @Travis Yes you can, [**here is jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eWHSJ/5/) You just need to add `$('#box_expand').hide();` to the begining. I'm glad i could help, select accept answer, if it worked (:

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. I just accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) should do.

```
$("#addClass").click(function () {$('#the_box').toggleClass('box_expand')});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eWHSJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery's addClass("someClass") and removeClass("someclass"). You can use someting like this:

```
$("#AddClass").click( $("#the_box").addClass("someClass") );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no element got id=`AddClass` on html.

Comment: there's a button with the leyend "instructions" that got's that id... anyway i wanted to give you and example, but i missed wath you already did with your scrips, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thing to watch out for:

- Your first function passed in the `.click()` in missing the closing `}`. That will cause the JS to fail.
- In your JSfiddle, you haven't selected jQuery as a library, so your jQuery will not work.
- If you are trying to animate the whole thing, look into the .animate() or [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) jQuery methods.

Keep at it though, you are almost there!

I simplified your markup and made a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyHSr/

Hope it helps.

Comment: True enough. I wonder if the script could be placed at the bottom of the page though.

Comment: We gave same answer on same time, only difference was `.ready()` (:

Comment: @Travis, if they work out and upvote or two wouldn't hurt.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to add a closing brace and parentheses to your original listener function.  However, I'd suggest that, if you are trying to debug something like this in the future, you break down your script to the most minimal example you can to try and figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/XrUmr/

For example, to figure out the error you are having, you really only need this html:

```
<div id="the_box"> Something </div>
<button id="addClass"> Instructions </button>
<button id="removeClass"> Remove class </button>​
```

And this javascript:

```
 $("#addClass").click(function () {    
    $('#the_box').addClass('box_expand')
 });
 $("#removeClass").click(function () {
      $('#the_box').removeClass('box_expand');
 });
```

(with some css to differentiate between added and removed classes).

Also, you should try to find an editor that:

1. Automatically adds indentation (so you can more easily tell when you've missed an opening/close brace, etc)
2. Does syntax highlighting (again, helps to see these kinds of issues)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help and patience. I am an physiologist by trade and am trying to learn all of this as I go for a health and fitness site I am building. I ended up changing the div class to a div id and using the click function to hide/show. I think this will work, but I may play around with it some more, as I want it to load in the hidden state. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer has been chosen I just would like to suggest a nicely illustrated and rather whimsical way to learn Jquery http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery .

Hope this helps & good luck learning Jquery!